# Can I say "May I have a Nescafe or a water?"

Tags: questions

I know we can say I ordered a coffee meaning a cup of coffee but can I say the same with Nescafe or water or any other drink?

Answer (score 1):

#### Maybe. It depends on context.

It's fairly common for people to say things like "having a Coke," "having a beer", or "having a coffee". However, not all drinks are idiomatic to use that way, though; "having a wine" or "having a tea" sounds wrong to me, since you need to specify the container/quantity your beverage is in for them, like "a cup of tea" vs "a pot of tea", or "a glass of wine" vs "a bottle of wine". I'm not certain exactly what rule governs what forms of drink you're required to state the quantity, and which ones aren't (or if there even is a rule, rather than a mess of ad-hoc exceptions).

Alternately, you can specify precisely what type of tea or wine you're having, like "I'm having a Chai Latte"; this is often done in the context of ordering from a menu, like saying "I'll have a Merlot Red" to the waiter at a restaurant. For the example you mentioned, "having a Nescafe" would be allowed if it's understood what "a Nescafe" means - if you're ordering from a menu, or if someone asks you what kind of coffee you're drinking.

With regards to water specifically, "I'm having a water" isn't allowed, but when ordering from a restaurant, "I'll have a water" is fine.